# Python - Use 'set' to find the different items in list

Tags: python, compare

I need to compare two lists in Python, and I know about using the `set` command to find similar items, but is there a another command I could use that would automatically compare them, instead of having to code for it?

I would like to find the items that aren't in each one. Say list one is as follows:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

and list two is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

I want to find that `5` is missing from the list, hopefully by a command, but I do know how to loop through comparing.

Comment: What do you need to compare? Do you need to find the matching items? What exactly do you need to do?

Comment: Ugh, no need to vote to close yet. Give OP a chance to modify the question and provide context.

Comment: I mean I would like to find the items that _aren't_ in each one. Say list one is as follows: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] and list two is: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]. I want to find that 5 is missing from the list, hopefully by a command, but I do know how to loop through comparing

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Looks like you need symmetric difference:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [3,4,5]

print(set(a)^set(b))


>>> [1,2,4,5]
```

Answer (score 62):

The [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) are a good place to start. Here are a couple examples that might help you determine how you want to compare your sets.

To find the intersection (items that are in both sets):

```
>>> a = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> b = set([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> a & b
set([4, 5, 6])
```

To find the difference (items that only in one set):

```
>>> a = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> b = set([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> a - b
set([1, 2, 3])
>>> b - a
set([7, 8, 9])
```

To find the symmetric difference (items that are in one or the other, but not both):

```
>>> a = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> b = set([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> a ^ b
set([1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: Would the finding the difference example work if lists a and b had thousands of elements? Basically is it a workable solution to deal with scaling later on?

Answer (score 5):

A simple list comprehension

```
In [1]: a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 

In [2]: b=[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]

In [3]: [i for i in a if i not in b]
Out[3]: [5]
```

Comment: This finds items in a that are not in b, rather than finding items not in each.. so is the difference but not symmetric difference.

Comment: @Spaceghost - true. I just used OPs example straight off

Comment: OP asked for items not in each one.. otherwise, would have upvoted this.